# efficient way to parse a text file for data

Tags: c#, text-parsing

I have a text file with the below format.

```
FILE_TYPE=MULTI_PHYS_TABLE;


PART '74AVC1T45_Q100'
:PART_NUMBER|PACK_TYPE|MATERIAL|NAME|FP_TECH|IP=SCH_CHECKLEVEL|CLASS|FSP_LOGICAL_MODEL|AML|LPID|MFG_STATUS|PART_CHECKLEVEL|DESCRIPTION|MFG_NAME_1|MFG_NAME_2|MFG_PN_10|ASI_MODEL|ENVCOMP|FPT_CHECKLEVEL|MFG_STATUS_10|MFG_NAME_4|MFG_NAME_3|MFG_NAME_6|MFG_NAME_5|MFG_NAME_8|LOGIC_2|MFG_NAME_7|LOGIC_1|JEDEC_TYPE|MFG_NAME_9|MAX_OPER_TEMP|MFG_PN_8|MFG_PN_9|MAX_REFLOW_TEMP|HEIGHT|MFG_PN_4|MFG_PN_5|MFG_PN_6|MFG_PN_7|STATUS|MFG_PN_1|MFG_PN_2|MFG_PN_3|CREATED_BY|WEIGHT|SPEED_URL|LEAD_LENGTH|DESIGN_GROUP|DAYS|ALT_SYMBOLS|MIN_OPER_TEMP|MFG_NAME_10|MFG_STATUS_1|MFG_STATUS_3|MFG_STATUS_2|MFG_STATUS_9|MFG_STATUS_8|RPL|MFG_STATUS_5|MFG_STATUS_4|COMPONENT_TYPE|MFG_STATUS_7|MFG_STATUS_6|PART_NUMBER;
'G69247-001'|'XSON6'|'IC'|'74VC1T45_Q100'|'TK0'|'GENERIC' ('!')='BRONZE'|'IC'|''|''|''|''|'BRONZE'|'IC,LOG,TRANSCEIVE,SOT886,SN74AVC1T45,NI3S'|''|''|''|'G69247-001'|''|'BRONZE'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'TK0_LCC6_1500X1050_500_MA'|''|'125C'|''|''|''|'0.500 MM'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'http://example.com'|''|''|''|'()'|'-40C'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'SMALLSMT'|''|''|'G69247-001':CDS_LW_PART_NUMBER='G69247-001'
'G69247-001'|'XSON6'|'EMPTY'|'74VC1T45_Q100'|'TK0'|'GENERIC' ('!')='BRONZE'|'IO'|''|''|''|''|'BRONZE'|'IC,LOG,TRANSCEIVE,SOT886,SN74AVC1T45,NI3S'|''|''|''|'G69247-001'|''|'BRONZE'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'TK0_LCC6_1500X1050_500_MA'|''|'125C'|''|''|''|'0.500 MM'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'http://example.com'|''|''|''|'()'|'-40C'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'SMALLSMT'|''|''|'G69247-001':CDS_LW_PART_NUMBER='G69247-001'
END_PART


PART '74CBTLV3126'
:PART_NUMBER|PACK_TYPE|MATERIAL|NAME|FP_TECH|IP=SCH_CHECKLEVEL|CLASS|FSP_LOGICAL_MODEL|AML|LPID|MFG_STATUS|PART_CHECKLEVEL|DESCRIPTION|MFG_NAME_1|MFG_NAME_2|MFG_PN_10|ASI_MODEL|ENVCOMP|FPT_CHECKLEVEL|MFG_STATUS_10|MFG_NAME_4|MFG_NAME_3|MFG_NAME_6|MFG_NAME_5|MFG_NAME_8|LOGIC_2|MFG_NAME_7|LOGIC_1|JEDEC_TYPE|MFG_NAME_9|MAX_OPER_TEMP|MFG_PN_8|MFG_PN_9|MAX_REFLOW_TEMP|HEIGHT|MFG_PN_4|MFG_PN_5|MFG_PN_6|MFG_PN_7|STATUS|MFG_PN_1|MFG_PN_2|MFG_PN_3|CREATED_BY|WEIGHT|SPEED_URL|LEAD_LENGTH|DESIGN_GROUP|DAYS|ALT_SYMBOLS|MIN_OPER_TEMP|MFG_NAME_10|MFG_STATUS_1|MFG_STATUS_3|MFG_STATUS_2|MFG_STATUS_9|MFG_STATUS_8|RPL|MFG_STATUS_5|MFG_STATUS_4|COMPONENT_TYPE|MFG_STATUS_7|MFG_STATUS_6|PART_NUMBER;
'G21997-001'|'QFN'|'EMPTY'|'74CBTLV3126'|'TK0'|'GENERIC' ('!')='BRONZE'|'IO'|''|''|''|''|'BRONZE'|'IC,LOG,Q-SWITCH,QFN,74CBTLV3126,BUS'|''|''|''|'G21997-001'|''|'BRONZE'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'TK0_LCC14_3100X2600_500_DF1650X1150_MA'|''|'125C'|''|''|''|'1.000 MM'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'http://example.com'|''|''|''|'()'|'-40C'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'LCC'|''|''|'G21997-001':CDS_LW_PART_NUMBER='G21997-001'
'G21997-001'|'QFN'|'IC'|'74CBTLV3126'|'TK0'|'GENERIC' ('!')='BRONZE'|'IC'|''|''|''|''|'BRONZE'|'IC,LOG,Q-SWITCH,QFN,74CBTLV3126,BUS'|''|''|''|'G21997-001'|''|'BRONZE'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'TK0_LCC14_3100X2600_500_DF1650X1150_MA'|''|'125C'|''|''|''|'1.000 MM'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'http://example.com'|''|''|''|'()'|'-40C'|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|''|'LCC'|''|''|'G21997-001':CDS_LW_PART_NUMBER='G21997-001'
END_PART

END.
```

I want to extract the information between `PART` and `END_PART`. As you can see the columns and values are separated by a `|` symbol.
I am trying the following way

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(PTFPath);
    string line;
    while (((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) && line.StartsWith(StartPart))
    {
        string symbolName = line.Split(' ')[1];
        //loop again until we see END_PART
        //Record the column order as its the first row and remaining rows as the values of the part
    }
```

But this may result in a n-square complexity or possibly n-cube. I am just wondering if there is a better,efficient & faster way to parse this file in C#

Comment: Why does this result in `O(n²)` complexity?  By my reckoning, you're already doing this the most efficient way possible.

Comment: So, I thought...if the inner loop has m rows we need to iterate m times n from the outer loop which makes it `O(n*m)` right. so worst case would be `O(n2)`. please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Split in my opinion takes O(n) time and loop above that is for number of rows and even then after you loop for all found strings still its complexity should be O(n) i.e. number of rows * noOfColumns, you should store the result of split, don't use it every time you need a string

Comment: You have to split every line to make this work anyway.  You can debate the relative merits of Big O all day long, but it's not going to matter.

Comment: You need one loop to go over the lines. Inside that loop, once you've found the line you're interested in (`PART '...'`), you need to start dealing with the lines after it, until the `END_PART` line. The way you deal with these is by splitting them using the pipe delimiter, and loop over the results of that split. This means that at the very least you need two loops.